# Capture http token with tcpdump

Tags: curl, http, tcpdump

My server runs curl commands to some API using a token. For example:

```
curl --header "Private-Token: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" http://mysite.example.com/api/v4/any
```

Can i capture with `tcpdump` all of the requests to that API with this a specific token? If so, How? Other ideas will be great as well.

Comment: If curl is making the requests and getting the answer, why not saving the answer? Why using tcpdump at all?

Comment: I just want to investigate something using tcpdump. That's is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For listening to HTTP traffic with `tcpdump`, and seeing the actual packets contents, you can do it with:

```
sudo tcpdump -X -s 1500 "port 80 and host mysite.example.com"
```

However, filtering on data can only be done at specific packet positions in `tcpdump` and is not viable on this case.

So in addition, you can use also `ngrep` to listen for **lines** with the specific string data on the network interface.

```
sudo ngrep -q "Private-Token: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa" "port 80 and host mysite.example.com"
```

As for the actual host/port filters, see this (short) summary about `tcpdump`/BPF filters: [TCPDUMP expressions](http://www.workrobot.com/sysadmin/security/tcpdump_expressions.html)

Also, the `wireshark` @StephenHarris recommendation, is quite good, for having a graphical interface. To do a `tcpdump` writing raw data in a file for later use in `wireshark`, you do:

```
sudo tcpdump -X -s 1500 "port 80 and host mysite.example.com" -w mycapture.pcap
```

You can also capture the packet requests at application level, using `sysdig`. (Not so sure about the answers without testing)

```
sudo sysdig -s 2000 -A -c echo_fds fd.port=80 and evt.buffer contains "Private-Token: aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
```

Comment: See also `wireshark` which can capture data, _or_ read pre-saved `tcpdump` pcap files, and filter on contents.

Comment: @StephenHarris `wireshark` for a graphical interface is a good recommendation.